# Dragging file with Alt+Cmd from Finder does not use NSDragOperationLink flag in draggingSourceOperationMask

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, finder

I have a simple app that accepts dropping files from Finder.

I want to support 3 different dragging types:

- move
- copy
- link (make alias)

When pressing Alt+Cmd while dragging, Finder usually creates an alias (link). However, in my app in `draggingEntered:` the flag `NSDragOperationLink` is not set in that case.

Below are the various flags for the different modifier key combinations:

```
move (no keys): Private, Delete, Copy, Generic, Link, Move, All_Obsolete, Every
copy (Alt)    :                  Copy,                      All_Obsolete, Every
link (Alt+Cmd):                  Copy, Generic,             All_Obsolete, Every
```

Note how in the last case the Link flag is not set. How could I tell in `performDragOperation:` that I need to create an alias?

Do I really have to check the modifier keys in the current event? I'd much rather have a clean solution via the source dragging operation mask...

Tested on 10.8.5 and 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register first your dragged types in the code using

```
      registerfordraggedtypes: api
```

Comment: I have done that: `[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know it's a very old thread but it still comes up in search results.

For drag-and-drop operations that span applications you have to hold down Control to filter for the Link flag.

In the online documentation for `NSDraggingInfo draggingSourceOperationMask` there's a table showing how the modifier keys are handled but it's wrong (it seems to be describing how the Finder works). If you can dig up older documentation on the drag-and-drop API it shows a different filtering algorithm where Option filters for Copy, Command filters for Generic, and Control filters for Link. That's the filtering algorithm that the OS still applies to inter-application drag-and-drop.